# Equivalent of executing a file (with shebang line) by entering its path?

Tags: shell-script, executable, shebang

Say I have a file *hello*:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World!"
```

Provided the executable bit is set on that file, I can execute it by entering its path on the prompt:

```sh
$ ./hello
Hello World!
```

Is there a more explicit equivalent to the above? Something akin to:

```sh
$ execute hello
```

I know I can pass *hello* as an argument to `/bin/sh`, but I'm looking for a solution that automatically uses the interpreter specified in the shebang line

My use case for this is to execute script files that do not have the executable flag set. These files are stored in a git repository, so I would like to avoid setting their executable flag or having to copy them to another location first.

Comment: How about simply extracting the interpreter from the `#!` line with `INTERPRETER=$(sed -n ' /^#!/s///p;1q' "YOUR_SCRIPT")` and then `"${INTERPRETER:-/bin/sh}" "YOUR_SCRIPT"`? Make a script out of it.

Comment: Over on [ubuntu.se]: [Is there a command for running a script according to its shebang line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/850384/158442)

Comment: You can use the `command_not_found_handle()` feature of bash to catch commands like `hello` (where `hello` is not found in `PATH`), but not for `./hello` or `path/to/hello`.

Comment: git can hold executable flags.  The file system underneath must support it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `perl`:

```
perl hello
```

From [`perl` docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun):

> If the #! line does not contain the word "perl" nor the word "indir",  the program named after the #! is executed instead of the Perl interpreter. This is slightly bizarre, but it helps people on machines that don't do #!, because they can tell a program that their SHELL is /usr/bin/perl, and Perl will then dispatch the program to the correct interpreter for them.

([via](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850384/is-there-a-command-for-running-a-script-according-to-its-shebang-line))

Comment: And I thought I'd never find a use for Perl again!

Comment: However, note that this isn't exactly the same as doing it via the kernel: For one, Perl may handle multiple arguments the hashbang line differently than the system. As far as I can see, `perl` only uses the first, while Linux sticks everything into one argument, and some other systems might support more than one. E.g. `#!/bin/bash -x -u` gets started with just `-x` under Perl, while under macOS, Bash gets both options, and on Linux, it gets the single arg `-x -u` (which produces an error). Also if the system supports setuid scripts, it's impossible to emulate that with `perl`.

Comment: To me this wouldn't be a more explicit equivalent to `./hello` but rather a source of confusion.

Comment: @Aaron. Then you should read the question again. `./hello` works only with executable files. OP explicitly doesn't want that.

Comment: @pLumo I didn't really have that part in mind at the time of my comment, but my point still stands. I find using the `perl` interpreter to execute anything else than perl code confusing and would avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Aaron I agree that it's confusing, but it doesn't seem that there is any alternative besides rolling my own (which I want to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

The following Perl5 script, with no error checking, grabs the hashbang line and calls it to execute the script passed as an argument: (simplifying and streamlining per ilkkachu's comment), to avoid reading the whole file...

```
open FH, ("<",$ARGV[0])
$line = <FH>;
close FH;
if ($line =~ /^\#\!(.*)/) {
    $engine = $1;
    exec("$engine $ARGV[0]");
}
```

Comment: Besides being pointless, this doesn't even work. But if it worked, it would still be worse than perl's built-in shebang parser. First, because it doesn't allow spaces between the `!` and the path. And second, because it allows injecting shell code via the filename.

Comment: By the way, it seems that the bash shell, at least, ignores spaces prepended to executables' filenames, so there's no need to make the regexp more complicated to allow for whitespaces...